# How to simulate a key press by pressing a different key

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, key

I want to hide the "suggested" options list that appears underneath the search input when you start typing something on the Wordpress search plugin, what I need specifically is to fire the "Escape" key event when I press down the "Delete" key, I tried the following jquery function but it doesn't work as I expected.

```
$('form.search-form').keydown(function (e) {

// keycode for Delete key
if (e.keyCode == 46) {
      var a = $.Event("keydown");
      // keycode for Esc key
      a.which = 27;
      a.keyCode = 27;
      $(document).trigger(a); 
}});
```

Any help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Updated (original question was unclear)

[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/UyeGOBA/5/edit)

When the delete key is pressed, change the `keyCode` to the `esc` key, then use `trigger` to simulate a press of `esc`.

```
$('input').keydown(function (e) {
  // keycode for delete
  if (e.keyCode == 46) {
    console.log('delete key pressed.');
    e.keyCode = 27;
    $(this.target).trigger(e);
  }
});

$('input').keydown(function (e) {
  // keycode for esc
  if (e.keyCode == 27) {
    console.log('esc key pressed.');
  }
});
```

#### Old answer (leaving this here because it is similar.)

Your question is an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You don't need to fire another keydown, event, you just need to repeat the same functionality, so extract the `esc` event's code into a function and reuse in the `del` key's event. [Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/UyeGOBA/1/edit)

```
$('input').keydown(function (e) {
  // keycode for delete
  if (e.keyCode == 46) {
    myFunction(e);
  }
});

$('input').keydown(function (e) {
  // keycode for esc
  if (e.keyCode == 27) {
    myFunction(e);
  }
});

function myFunction() {
  alert('Look, Ma! Code reuse!'); 
}
```

#### Better yet, do this!

[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/UyeGOBA/3/edit)

```
$('input').keydown(function (e) {
  // keycodes for delete and esc
  if (e.keyCode == 46 || e.keyCode == 27) {
    myFunction(e);
  }
});

function myFunction() {
  alert('Look, Ma! Code optimization!'); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately that wasn't what I was looking for. I'll explain on another words, what I need is to fire the same actions associated to the Esc key to another key(Delete in this case).

Comment: @peterbetis that is EXACTLY what I did, and I showed you two approaches.

Comment: @peterbetis do you not understand? In both examples, `myFunction` is called whether you use the `esc` key or `delete` key. Both keys are functioning exactly the same way - exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: I appreciate your effort probably I didn't explained well enough. Thanks again but your solution just calls a particular function wether any of the two key events are pressed down. What I need is to attach a key the same actions triggered by another key by default.

Comment: @peterbetis see my updated answer. I would have asked "How to simulate a keypress using a different key?". Talking about events is what made the question unclear.